# How to use Jenkins Git Publisher to check two builds prior to pushing to development stream?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there an easy way to setup the Git Publisher in Jenkins to check for multiple builds before pushing code from either? For example, we have a C++ and a J2EE codebase that we build nightly - if these two get out of sync, we have environment issues.

Is there a way that we can use the Git Publisher plugin to check for two successful builds prior to merging the code for those streams?

For example, we have origin/int and origin/dev - we push to origin int, have Jenkins build based off this branch, and if successful we merge to dev. However, the way it's currently setup is that either C++ or J2EE can build successfully while the other fails, and that stream will still get pushed.  I.e.,:

- J2EE Origin/Int -> build succeeds -> merge to Origin/dev
- C++ Origin/Int -> build fails -> don't merge to Origin/dev
- Developers then rebase both streams, only now the C++ stream is out
  of date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with the git publisher. But you could maybe solve it by using an intermediate git branch and a third job:

- J2EE Origin/Int -> build succeeds -> merge to Origin/jenkins_built
- C++ Origin/Int -> build fails -> don't merge to Origin/jenkins_built
- Merge Job: if both succeeds -> merge both jenkins_built to dev

You might want to use the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) or the [Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) one to only run your Merge Job when both integration builds have passed.